# HTML Jquery get HTTP Response details on pageload

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML page that integrates with Payment gateway. [test.PayU.in]
Gateway redirects to different HTML pages depending upon Success/ Failure.
On success HTML pageload I tried to get HTTPResponse code, but its not correct.
Please give some suggestions.

HTML pageload

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",   
     url: "https://test.payu.in/response.php",   
     async: false,
     success : function(data, textStatus)
     {
         alert(data);
         alert(textStatus);
     },
     error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
     {
         alert(XMLHttpRequest);
         alert(textStatus);
         alert(errorThrown);
     }

});
alert(new XMLHttpRequest().response);
```

Comment: are you getting any errors ?

Comment: no data, no textStatus and no errors. I think it is creating a new instance of HTTPRequest

Comment: if you want the full code, I can mail you.

Comment: Did you check the headers on POSTMAN ?